# Evaluate given string as array or not using regex

Tags: regex

I need to find a way to detect whether the given string is of Array type or not. [Nested Arrays]

Arrays can be string array `["abc","def","ghi"]`  or
Numeric array `[1,2.0]` or a composite `["abc" , 1]`

Tab and newline characters are also supported

Invalid arrays =>

1. `[a,b,c]` (Without quotes)
2. `["ab","cd","fe",]` (Empty values)
3. `[,]` (Empty values)

Valid arrays =>

1. `["ab","hg1",["abc" , [4,7,9.5,[2,"5.6"]]]]`
2. `[]`
3. `["ab"     , "cd"]`

I tried and wrote the regex for 1-d arrays:

```
\[(((\d*(\.\d+)?)|("((?!").)*"))((?:,\d+(\.\d+)?)*|(?:,"((?!").)*")*)*)\]
```

Is it possible to recursively apply this regex on nested arrays? Because, this regex does not validate nested arrays.

Comment: What about nested arrays?

Comment: Is that in Python? Try `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: Its easy to do the elements, however you need a regex engine that does  recursion (balanced text), for the nested array delimiter. So, this would be engines like Dot-Net, Perl, PCRE, Boost, and I think Ruby as well. Otherwise, don't even try with a regex.

Comment: Does your language have a JSON parser? Parse it as JSON, then check whether it succeeded, that the value is an array, and all the elements are either numbers, strings, or arrays (and continue this recursively).

Comment: What is the regex flavor? Tool? Language?

Comment: I use Scala and Pattern,Matcher classes. Guess it is Java regex engine!